# Meaning & Etyomology: 博眼球?

Tags: meaning, etymology

The only meaning of 博眼球 I've been able to come across is the following from a 百度知道 answer:

> 回头率高，吸引人的意思

but is it really that simple, is that all it means? 'An eyeball-turner?'

What does 博 mean here?

Where did this word originate from?

The pictures associated with this word seems to show that it is of a more perverted nature but it is also used in a more normal fashion elsewhere, e.g.: 漳州：商家为博眼球 促销竟请来"毛主席".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word `博` is usually used with another word `得`(or `取`).

The meaning of `博` here is also the same as `得`, which means `get`, or more precisely `to get`.

When you translate it into English, I'd use `to attract` instead.

So the whole sentence could be `To attract more eyeballs`.

Comment: or "eye-catching"

Comment: @AngelLeliel haha good one.

Comment: 博 is bet，I think

Comment: @Jacob, nope, I know where you are coming from. But it's not the same as `赌博`. Try to think of it as in `博取众家之长`.

Comment: @JustinXL Those questions started me thinking Chinese seriously.Though I am from China,many learners knowing Chinese more than me,I am a learner ,too.And this is also helpful for me to learn English.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, 博 and 搏 are the same word in ancient, it means to fight, to confront with another man, and 博眼球 means confront with others to win eyeball（eye-catch instead）, so it means to draw and win attention from others.
And, if you see 搏眼球，that's correct too.
Besides, 赌博，here 博 also has the meaning to confront others (or sometime like fate) in the gambling.

Comment: `博 and 搏 are the same word in ancient`, Where did you get this from??

Comment: I don't know if you can understand this:
实际“博”字是标准的形声字，其本义在金文中和演变过程已经详细考察与研究，为搏斗之搏本字，大通也含义当是一种假借义。后世假借义行，本义废，故造“搏”字代替其本义。

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. But still, I think the meaning is more towards `取` in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

博    gamble for

眼球  eyeballs (here means attention)

博眼球 compete for attention

Answer (score 0):

Get people's attension by some means.

It often use as derogatory sence and your example is this type. 博 means get something with please or powerful way， like joked to let people see him.